# Creating a chat with nodejs ws (einaros)

Tags: node.js, websocket

Yesterday I started using this module. I'm trying to make a chat for do something with websockets.

I have the problem, that I don't know how to pass the message that sends a client to the server for then show it for all users. In the server side I have this code:

```
var ipaddress = 'localhost';
var port = 8080;

var WebSocketServer = require('ws').Server
    , ws = new WebSocketServer({host:ipaddress, port:port});

ws.on('connection', function(ws) {
    console.log('New connection');
    ws.on('message', function(message) {
        ws.send(message);
    });
});

console.log('Listening to ' + ipaddress + ':' + port + ' ...');
```

And in the client side this other code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var content = $('#screen');
    var message = $('input[type="text"]').val();
    var ws = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8080');

    ws.onopen = function() {
        console.log('Connected');
    };

    $('input[type="button"]').click(function() {
        ws.send(message);
    });

    ws.onmessage = function(msg) {
        console.log('Received message from server: ' + msg.data);
        addMessage(msg.data);
    }

    function addMessage(message) {
        content.prepend('<p><span>' + message + '</span></p>');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's explained [here](https://github.com/einaros/ws#server-sending-broadcast-data):

```
var WebSocketServer = require('ws').Server
  , wss = new WebSocketServer({host:ipaddress, port:port});

wss.broadcast = function(data) {
  for (var i in this.clients)
    this.clients[i].send(data);
};

// use like this:
wss.on('connection', function(ws) {
  ws.on('message', function(message) {
    wss.broadcast(message);
  });
});
```

Comment: With the second part of the code I have the next error: C:\xampp\htdocs\simpleChat\server.js:16
        ws.broadcast(message);
           ^
TypeError: Object #<WebSocket> has no method 'broadcast'

Comment: @Alexbha I edited my answer, I missed that you're overwriting the `ws` variable so instead of calling `broadcast` on the server (where it's defined), you're calling it on the socket (where it's not).

Comment: I put the snippet in my server side file. When I send a message it does not appear on the terminal nor log. Should I change something in my client side file? Sorry if i'm very noob but it's the first time with this

Comment: @Alexbha I tested using `wscat` and that seemed to work okay. I'll try and see if I can create a simple standalone setup tomorrow :)

Comment: @Alexbha here's a standalone server: [gist](https://gist.github.com/robertklep/5b299451d8bd450844a8). Each client will sent a random message every second, and that message will be broadcasted to all connected clients by the server.

Comment: Ok! Now it works, I missed copy the last line. I will try to adapt the code to my code. Thanks

Comment: @IbrahimApachi this is server-side code, meant to be run in a Javascript runtime like Node.js and not in a browser.

Comment: Is it possible to make a `broadcast group` using `ws`?

Comment: @SuhailGupta I don't see why not, it's just that you would have to implement something like that yourself, much like the broadcast function presented in the answer

Answer (score 0):

```
var WebSocketServer = require('ws').Server
var webserver = new WebSocketServer({ port:3000 });

webserver.on("message",function(message) {
    webserver.clients.forEach(function(client) {
        client.send(message);
    });  
}):
```

Comment: Please add short explanation to your answer.